# Webform Conditional - 'set to' membership type

Tags: webform-civicrm, condition

Using Drupal 7.56, CiviCRM 4.7.22 and Webform 7.x-4.15.

I have two fields in a webform: one containing gender and the second containing a selection of membership types. If the gender is, for example, female I want to use the webform conditionals to set the membership type to a specific value. What value must I enter in the field displayed when I select 'set to'?

Answer (score 1):

Enter the Membership Type ID and that will display the correct value in the webform.

Answer (score 0):

How would I find the ID of the value I want? e.g. in your example, what is the Membership Type ID? Is it some code or just the name of the field?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: You can go to [yoursite]civicrm/admin/member/membershipType?reset=1  look up the membership in question, right click open-new tab "Edit" button, then the URL will  look like:

[yoursite]/civicrm/admin/member/membershipType/add?action=update&id=8&reset=1

id=8 in this case